# Python Selenium don't get all results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hey Guys it is my first time asking a question here so pls dont be to harsh to me and my english is not the yellow from the egg as well.

i have a problem i tried to webscrape companys but i am able to get all company names but if i try to scrape for the phone number and other data i only get the first 4 results hope someon can help me thanks in advance

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/KFZ/50968")

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "gs_treffer"))
    )
    
except:
    driver.quit

element = driver.find_element_by_id ('cmpbntyestxt')
element.click()

Firma = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2")
for firma in Firma:

    print(firma.text)

PLZ = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber")
for plz in PLZ:
   
    print(plz.text)



driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll into each element panel, and then you can interact with them.

You can try the below solution :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/KFZ/50968")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='cmpbntyestxt']/.."))).click()

lngth = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h2[@data-wipe-name='Titel']"))
print(lngth)
j = 0
scrolling = 0
for item in range(lngth):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h2[@data-wipe-name='Titel']")
    lst = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='gs_treffer']/child::article")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", lst[scrolling])
    time.sleep(1)
    print(elements[j].text)
    print(elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//following-sibling::address/p[2]").text)
    j = j + 1
    scrolling = scrolling + 1
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/SeleniumSO/Chrome.py
16
Scherschel Andreas
0221 38 59 93
Scherschel Andreas Dipl.-Ing. KFZ-Sachverst.
0221 38 59 93
La Linea Franca GmbH,Volvo Vertragshändler KFZ-Handel
0221 8 00 60-0
Kuehler Willems Services UG
0221 3 76 11 11
Autoservice Baum
0221 38 59 31
Mückl u. Rehse GbR Ingenieurbüro
0221 93 46 49-0
Procar Automobile GmbH & Co. KG - Köln Süd
0221 37 69 80
Allianz Versicherung Wolfgang Georg
0221 3 40 49 51
Pohlen Robert Autoservice
0221 37 84 72
Barmenia Versicherung - Norin Amraei
01522 6 22 70 04
Auto-Kühlerbau
0221 3 76 11 11
Barmenia Versicherung - Anders OHG
0221 9 85 49 30
Barmenia Versicherung - Kevin Wimmer
0176 70 29 27 17
Barmenia Versicherung - Yazdan Izadi
0221 9 85 49 30
GTÜ Prùfstelle Köln Bayenthal
0221 93 46 49-0
Continentale: T & T Versicherungsservice
0221 34 02 91 10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what i was looking for i didnt know you actualy have to order selenium to scroll down i was probably to spoiled because i worked with HTML  only sites before :D

Comment: oh and can you maybe tell me how you found //following-sibling::address/p[2] ?

Comment: oh sorry just saw youre comment what do you mean with request?

Comment: I am asking this cause you tagged Selenium in your question, and you've accepted answer in request module, see above the green color.

Comment: oh i did it because i found it interesting that you are able to do it with another import

Comment: oh wait a moment now i see it you can only accept one answer as answer sorry just fixed it just wanted to show my appreciation to anyone who took time out of his day to help me sorry

Comment: It's upto you, but you should have been more clearer with your question at first place

Comment: sorry so i tried to accept every anwser but yeah the rest is history :D thanks for letting me know

Comment: about the thing to make my question more clearer do mean the tags?

Comment: about the thing to make my question more clearer do mean the tags?  -Yes we look for tags before answering, if you had mentioned request module, I would not have answered this question since I don't know that module very well

Comment: ok thank you i will be more carefull next time. and can you maybe explain how you got //following-sibling::address/p[2] couldnt find this xxpath?

Comment: following-sibling is for the siblings which are after the current node we are in. I saw it was address, please see HTML dom for more clear view. Also once I reach to address node, I saw the desire elements are in p tag, more specific the second p tag so I used `p[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape all the data from the landing page using requests module as well.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/KFZ/50968'

def get_lazyloaded_details(soup):
    all_details = []
    for lazyload_data in soup.select("article[data-lazyloaddata]"):
        container = json.loads(lazyload_data.get("data-lazyloaddata"))
        name = container['name']

        for item in container['trefferButtonListList']['trefferButtonListList']:
            for elem in item:
                if elem['gcLink']['text']=='E-Mail':
                    email = elem['gcLink']['href'].split("?")[0].split(":")[1]

                elif elem['gcLink']['text']=='Anrufen':
                    phone = elem['gcLink']['href'].split(":")[1]

                elif elem['gcLink']['text']=='Mehr Details':
                    detail_page_link = elem['gcLink']['href']

        all_details.append([name,email,phone,detail_page_link])

    return all_details


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    resp = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    all_details = get_lazyloaded_details(soup)
    
    for item in soup.select("article:not([data-lazyloaddata])"):
        name = item.select_one("h2[data-wipe-name]").get_text(strip=True)
        email = item.select_one("a.contains-icon-email").get("href").split("?")[0].split(":")[1]
        phone = item.select_one("p.mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber").text
        detail_page_link = item.select_one("a.contains-icon-details").get("href")
        all_details.append([name,email,phone,detail_page_link])

    for element in all_details:
        print(element)
```

Output (truncated):

```
['Scherschel Andreas', 'info@scherschel.com', '0221 38 59 93', 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/5cac50a0-a60e-49ef-8937-2f0a7bcad241']
['Scherschel Andreas Dipl.-Ing. KFZ-Sachverst.', 'info@scherschel.com', '0221 38 59 93', 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/5cac50a0-a60e-49ef-8937-2f0a7bcad241']
['La Linea Franca GmbH,Volvo Vertragshändler KFZ-Handel', 'buschdorf@lalinea.de', '0221800600', 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/1db12570-6d7c-4fe2-ab3d-d0c02e74324a']
['Kuehler Willems Services UG', 'info@kuehler-willems.eu', '02213761111', 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/54d91f8c-eebe-41e3-962e-acdbfac6be46']
```